# Intercepting method of an tomcat application with aop

Tags: java, tomcat, aop, aspectj

I have a problem which is hard to explain so lets get started:

Context: I have a application running on a tomcat server Lets call it "admin". The admin have an import/export function. Our own application is an extension to that and we need to gather some information when the "admin apps" use the import/export function.

Problem: The third party jar that contain the class ImportController is located there: `~/someFolder/admin/WEB-INF/lib/admin.jar`. The goal is to gather the Old project ID and the new Project ID so that our extension can link our class to the right project. Since i know the method signature i though i could use AOP to do so.

Idea: The idea i came with is to put something like `idHiJacker.jar` that would contain a single pointcut and advice into the `~/someFolder/admin/WEB-INF/lib/` and enable load-time weaving. That advice would simply put the information into an xml file so our extension would be able to read it when we want to put the link back after a project import.

Also i must say I'm a pure newbie with AOP and web stuff. But i do not wish to import a monster for just doing this small operation with AOP. At the moment im reading on aspectJ and AspectWerkz

Question:

- 1) Am I in the right direction? Do you see anything that would make this idea not work at all?
- 2) If this is possible what would be the good practice to do it in a very clean manner?
- 3) Should i do it with AspectJ? AspectWerkz? Or Something else?
- 4) Am i doing this for nothing? Is there an easier way to do that operation?

Edit: Also if you have good tutorial to link with answer, it would be awesome

Thanks for your time and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question:
>
> ```
> 1) Am I in the right direction? Do you see anything that would make this idea not work at all?
> ```

I can't see any reason why this will not work. `Aspect Oriented Programming` and `cross-cutting` concerns apart, the notion of `advice` is to execute some before or after some other pointcut and often to influence the behavior of that advised function. You are doing exactly that here.

> ```
> 2) If this is possible what would be the good practice to do it in a very clean manner?
> ```

There is some inherent chaos with aspects/advices -- since the control flow is hijacked more then a simple sequential reading of code is needed to understand whats going on.

> ```
> 3) Should i do it with AspectJ? AspectWerkz? Or Something else?
> ```

I have never used AspectWerkz but I have very good experience with AspectJ; especially in terms of the support here on stackoverflow and perhaps even more on its mailing list.

> ```
> 4) Am i doing this for nothing? Is there an easier way to do that operation?
> ```

Unless you can change the code of import controller or change the clients to make extra calls to do the linking thing this interception based approach seems best IMHO.

Comment: Thank for the answer, The problem i have is, this is kinda hard to inject the AOP. I just noticed that the "admin apps server" is started with a complicated bash script. So first i have to figure out how to enable the load-time weaving

Comment: @drgn ltw is not very difficult. The big challenge will be to figure out how to modify the script to add the agent and the additional jar. Another alternative is to use compile time weaving to instrument the existing classes and replace the jar deployed jar with the instrumented jar. Not sure how that works if the jar is signed.

Comment: After putting a simple aop.xml into the WEB-INF, my jar that contain only an aspect (exported from eclipse jar with aspectJ support) and also adding the javaagent (previous comment) this is not working. The problem is i have no error message and i putted the verbose option in the aop.xml but i have no message comming from the weaver. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @drgn If you are going to AspectJ I strongly recommend joining the [aspectj-users mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/aspectj-users), big advantage being thatAndy Clement himself answers just about every question.

Comment: Besides, AspectWerkz hast been merged with AspectJ years ago and discontinued. Since v1.5 AspectJ basically contains the old AspectWerkz features plus its own old ones.

Answer (score 0):

I have suggestion for a simpler solution - use a decorator pattern to wrap around the third party ImportController, put your functionality before the third party library is called. You should be able to do this since you seem to have access to the admin application.

This is essentially doing what AOP is doing, but using code. Your approach using load time weaver should also work, but is in my opinion complicated - if you absolutely plan to go this way, do use AspectJ.

Comment: How will OP inject the decorated `ImportController` into the third party application?

Comment: This is not a bad idea at all, i will keep that in mind as a secondary solution since the "admin apps" is started with a complicated bash script and i might not successfully enable the load time weaving. Thank a lots for this good idea